# JavaScript debugging via Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

How to debug JavaScript using Firebug?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+to+debug+javascript+using+firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of **Firebug** for this check the below link will give you more info.

here is link check this : http://thecodecentral.com/2007/08/01/debug-javascript-with-firebug

http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/