# How can i debug jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948262/debug-javascript)

Every now and then i have one jquery object and i am not able to find whats inside it.
I had to try many combinations like see the class name , id and other attributes to see what is that variable and sometime by hiding it.

Is there any proper way of debugging the jquery object to see whats inside it?

Comment: do you have firebug add-on in your mozilla browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), [Chrome Developer Tools](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html).  These are some of the tools for some of the respective  browsers.

Some IDES like eclipse let you debug inline.

Also there is a javascript statement : `debugger;`, which you can use for this purpose .

Comment: If you are using firebug you can use lot of tracers :

console.log(object);
console.debug(object);
console.info(object);
console.trace(object); You name it, everything's there .

Comment: thanks buddy , i use firebug but i didn't knew i could use the above functions

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug or the chrome developer tools you can debug any javascript object.
You need to add a breakpoint just after the object initialization and then add the object to the watch panel.

Object members are displayed in a tree view.