# how can I know what external js file runs the script in html page

Tags: javascript, firebug

I use a free bootstrap template and I want to know how I can figure out what external js file loaded and runs the script in firebug. 
Let me explain clearly. suppose that there is a script when you mouse over the scroll bar, it's appeared and when you mouse leave, disappeared. I want to set it always appeared. So how can I know which external js file does that then modify it.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Generally you can see all files loaded within the *Net* panel and see the executed JavaScript files within the *Script* panel.

Comment: for example, you have written several .js file and just one of them hidden scroll bar when mouse leaves it and show it when mouse is over it. How do I know which external .js files do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948262/debug-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has a [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) allowing you to debug your JavaScript.
If you don't know where the code is that is executed, it has a feature called *Break On Next* ([image: Break On Next button]), which stops the script execution at the next executed JavaScript statement.

There are also [several other *Break On ...* features](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...) in the different panels. E.g. you can break the script execution as soon as the DOM tree is modified or when an AJAX request is done.